# Movable text in Opengl Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

How to show movable text in Android using Open GL?? Or is their any other way that show text movement without any jerk. I have tried Android animation and marquee but it was not reducing jerk. I need text moving on single line coming in from right and going out to left like in news headlines. In Open GL what should i do in renderer??

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    touchStart = new PointF();
    objs = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    sqobj = new  rendsquare();
    objs.setRenderer(sqobj);
    setContentView(objs);


    TextView editBox = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    editBox.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    editBox.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    editBox.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    editBox.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    editBox.setFocusable(true);
    editBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    editBox.setText("Hello GL testing 123 hello hello h r u i am fine hello u there hello! hello !! !! !! !!");

    addContentView(editBox, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

//Other one

```
public class SquaropnglActivity extends Activity {

private rendsquare sqobj;
private PointF touchStart;
private GLSurfaceView objs;
Animation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(300f, -300f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    touchStart = new PointF();
    objs = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    sqobj = new  rendsquare();
    objs.setRenderer(sqobj);
    setContentView(objs);

    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(1);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimation.setDuration(3000L);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    TextView editBox = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    editBox.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    editBox.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    editBox.setTextSize(40);
    editBox.setLines(1);
    editBox.setText("Hello GL testing 123 hello hello h r u i am fine hello u there hello! hello !! !! !! !!");

    addContentView(editBox, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

}

Comment: could you show us something (code) what you have tried so far?

Comment: other one is using android animation but both are showing jerks

Comment: I want to add text in renderer and want it movable

Comment: @Salman yr kuch solution mila is sawaal ka... I was searching the same and I found your question instead!! Aur, kaisa hai?? How is everything?

Comment: Thik thak tu suna ?? Android pay kab say kam karnay laga ?? Yar recall karna paray ga bhaut time ho gaya hai kuch yad nahi

Answer (score 1):

If you want do text rendering in opengl way, please write text drawing logic in your
`onDrawFrame(gl)` 
method and update text position on each frame update to have marquee animation.

For text rendering, please look into [OpenGL Text Rendering](http://fractiousg.blogspot.in/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html)

Haven't tested it. It should work for you. Best wishes.